# For loop execution problems (Processing)

Tags: java, for-loop, processing

This is a very easy question to answer, I'm sure. I'm trying to get the text to change to the next item in the array after it 'resets' and moves to the top of the screen (i.e. when when `y=-10`).

```
PFont font;
String words[] = {"FIRST", "SECOND", "THIRD", "FOURTH"};
String s="";
float y = 50.0;
float speed = 4;
float radius = 15.0;
int x;
void setup() {
   size(400, 400);
   smooth();
   font = loadFont("Aldrich-48.vlw");
   textFont(font);
   fill(0);
 }

void draw() {
  background(204);
  for (x=0; x<4; x++)
  {
   s=words[x]; 
   text(s, 20, y);  
  }
  y = y + speed;
  if (y >= height) {
    y = -10;
   x++;
   }
 }
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: What language is this? C, C++, something else?

Comment: OK, you told us what you're trying to do. What is your question about it? If it's not working, please explain what it's doing wrong.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, it's in Processing (Java). Instead of the text changing from "FIRST" on the first pass to "SECOND" on the second pass etc it just writes them all out overlapping on each other at the same time..

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, I didn't even need a for loop. I just needed this:

```
void draw()
{
    background(204);
    text(words[x], 20, y);
    y = y + speed;

    if (y >= height)
    {
        y = -10;
        x++;
    }
}
```